# Is there a way to select posts and print to a template page dynamically?

Tags: select, bulk

I'm trying to print posts by selecting posts and doing a bulk action to dynamically add them to a template page I already have set up.  Is this possible?

---

Update with more info:
I'm using this function found in [this](http://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-custom-bulk-action/) example.

More specific question: Can you pass part of a url from the admin to the front end?

```
function custom_bulk_action() {
        global $typenow;
        $post_type = $typenow;

        if($post_type == 'slides') {

            // get the action
            $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');  // depending on your resource type this could be WP_Users_List_Table, WP_Comments_List_Table, etc
            $action = $wp_list_table->current_action();

            $allowed_actions = array("export");
            if(!in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) return;

            // security check
            check_admin_referer('bulk-posts');

            // make sure ids are submitted.  depending on the resource type, this may be 'media' or 'ids'
            if(isset($_REQUEST['post'])) {
                $post_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['post']);
            }

            if(empty($post_ids)) return;

            // this is based on wp-admin/edit.php
            $sendback = remove_query_arg( array('exported', 'untrashed', 'deleted', 'ids'), wp_get_referer() );
            if ( ! $sendback )
                $sendback = admin_url( "edit.php?post_type=$post_type" );

            $pagenum = $wp_list_table->get_pagenum();
            $sendback = add_query_arg( 'paged', $pagenum, $sendback );

            switch($action) {
                case 'export':

                    // if we set up user permissions/capabilities, the code might look like:
                    //if ( !current_user_can($post_type_object->cap->export_post, $post_id) )
                    //  wp_die( __('You are not allowed to export this post.') );

                    $exported = 0;
                    foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) {

                        if ( !$this->perform_export($post_id) )
                            wp_die( __('Error exporting post.') );

                        $exported++;
                    }

                    $sendback = add_query_arg( array('exported' => $exported, 'ids' => join(',', $post_ids) ), $sendback );
                break;

                default: return;
            }

            $sendback = remove_query_arg( array('action', 'action2', 'tags_input', 'post_author', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', '_status',  'post', 'bulk_edit', 'post_view'), $sendback );

            wp_redirect($sendback);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please work on this question. There are at multiple ways to interpret your first sentence-- the only one carrying any information about the problem.

Comment: Updated with a little more info (it was a little vague).  Also, I've been researching for the last day for answers to my problem and this is just one of many ways that I've tried to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

So just thought I would update with the solution I came up with incase anyone run across this in the future.

What I did was rebuild the url in the function and pass the ids in the url to the template page.

```
    function custom_bulk_action() {
        global $typenow;
        $post_type = $typenow;

        if($post_type == 'post_type') {

            // get the action
            $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');  // depending on your resource type this could be WP_Users_List_Table, WP_Comments_List_Table, etc
            $action = $wp_list_table->current_action();

            $allowed_actions = array("export");
            if(!in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) return;

            // security check
            check_admin_referer('bulk-posts');

            // make sure ids are submitted.  depending on the resource type, this may be 'media' or 'ids'
            if(isset($_REQUEST['post'])) {
                $post_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['post']);
            }

            if(empty($post_ids)) return;

            // this is based on wp-admin/edit.php
            $sendback = get_site_url() . '/whatever/?';

            switch($action) {
                case 'export':

                    // if we set up user permissions/capabilities, the code might look like:
                    //if ( !current_user_can($post_type_object->cap->export_post, $post_id) )
                    //  wp_die( __('You are not allowed to export this post.') );

                    $exported = 0;
                    foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) {

                        if ( !$this->perform_export($post_id) )
                            wp_die( __('Error printeting post.') );

                        $exported++;
                    }

                    $sendback = add_query_arg( array('ids' => join(',', $post_ids) ), $sendback );
                break;

                default: return;
            }

            $sendback = remove_query_arg( array('action', 'action2', 'tags_input', 'post_author', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', '_status',  'post', 'bulk_edit', 'post_view'), $sendback );

            wp_redirect($sendback);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Once I got the ids in the url I put them into an array `$postIds = explode(',', $_GET['ids']);` and called them in the `WP_Query` args using `post__in`.

There's probably a bit of unnecessary code left in there but it gets the job done.